# openstreetmap tool routing + highway tags / road_class

Tags: routes, openstreetmap, graphhopper

For a project, I need to optimize routing between about 5000 locations. Now, for this test, we need to apply our own speed mapping based on the highway tags which makes it a lot harder. I found graphhopper, but that would cost a lot (because we can only use the routing api to get the highway tags, and we need the fastest route from every point to every point (=5000 x 5000 = 25 mil).

Does anyone know of an easier or cheaper tool/way to achieve this? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can install your own GrahpHopper instance for free.

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/66143/routing-highway-tags